# Extracting Description Of A Debian Package

Tags: python, debian-based

I am trying to extract the description of debian packages from the Packages.gz file using Python.
Is there any way to get only the description of the package, i.e the content after the Description: field.

The source file is :

```
Package: 2vcard
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Installed-Size: 108
Maintainer: Martin Albisetti <argentina@gmail.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 0.5-3
Filename: pool/main/2/2vcard/2vcard_0.5-3_all.deb
Size: 14300
MD5sum: d831fd82a8605e9258b2314a7d703abe
SHA1: e903a05f168a825ff84c87326898a182635f8175
SHA256: 2be9a86f0ec99b1299880c6bf0f4da8257c74a61341c14c103b70c9ec04b10ec
Description: perl script to convert an addressbook to VCARD file format
 2vcard is a little perl script that you can use to convert the
 popular vcard file format. Currently 2vcard can only convert addressbooks
 and alias files from the following formats: abook,eudora,juno,ldif,mutt,
 mh and pine.
 .
 The VCARD format is used by gnomecard, for example, which is used by the
 balsa email client.
Tag: implemented-in::perl, role::program, use::converting
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-debian would be helpful?

In detail, assume that `data` is a string containing the source file contents, then:

```
from debian import deb822
print deb822.Deb822(data.split("\n"))['Description']
```

would output the description